# Macbook pro still turn on when lid is opened after changing AutoBoot variable

Tags: macbook-pro, command-line, sleep-wake

I recently bought my first macbook, and I want it to not turn on when I open the lid. Searching online, the solution is by using

```
% sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00
```

But this doesn't work for me. I'm on macOS 12.1.

And to make sure the AutoBoot variable is changing, I tried

```
% nvram -p | grep  "Auto"
```

which outputs

```
AutoBoot    %00
```

So the variable is changing, and there has to be another setting I have to change to make it work.

Comment: Did you reboot after setting this variable?

Comment: Yes I did. The variable change persist after restarting, so it's not like I'm not able to change to the variable. There has to be something else that I need to do

Comment: I have not personally tested this feature on Monterey but, just as a general rule: Apple has full freedom to modify or remove such undocumented functionality at any time. There may not be anything that you can do if Apple decided that there was a good reason to do away with this particular variable.

Comment: Damn this really suck. I hope there is some fix to it, and not just apple having features I can't turn off.